# A content not crawler in SP2007 search service

Tags: 2007, crawling, enterprise-search

we have a SP2007 search service attached to our SP2007 server used to create and store some PDFs.
Every night an incremental crawl job starts, and everything works fine... but some night ago (4 sept 2014) the crawler missed a PDF! Now this PDF is not being crawled anymore.
Is it possible to insert this content in the index database?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

How about a full crawl? Did it run in the meantime?

If your comment to my question means that you do not have a full crawl running at all, I can assure you at some point you will run into problems. I am sorry to continue on the path of the full crawl, but I would try the following optimisations first and then run a full crawl to fix the issue:

1. Check out "[Best practices for search performance (Office SharePoint Server 2007)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340949(v=office.12).aspx)": Apart from the usual staff (better hardware, network bottlenecks etc), it contains simple to implement configuration advice for the db server
2. I would really enable blobcaching if you don't have this already. Apart from website performance it helps with crawling too. You might want to experiment with adding pdf files there too, especially if they are very big.
3. Try to break your content source into more than just one. Especially if you have frequently changing and infrequently changing content, you should create two sources with different (preferably not overlapping) schedules. This will allow you to break these 5 days into more manageable chunks.
4. In Central Administration > Operations > Services on Server > Office SharePoint Server Search Service Settings you can create a crawler impact rule to “request 64 documents at a time” in order to maximize the number of threads the crawler can use to index content (provided your servers can handle this)
5. Registry keys:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office Server\12.0\Search\Global\Gathering Manager

Try playing with these values (they are dependent on the available hardware) to see if you can accelerate the process:

FolderHighPriority: 500 Decimal
FilterProcessMemoryQuota: 208857600 Decimal
DedicatedFilterProcessMemoryQuota: 208857600 Decimal

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office Server\12.0\Search\Global\Gathering Manager: DeleteOnErrorInterval : 4 Decimal (how many times to retry a file that gives an error)

5. PDF I-Filter: The Adobe PDF I-Filter can only filter one file at a time and that will slow crawls down. You can buy a retail PDF filter instead

All these provided you are running a healthy environment. If you are receiving error in the Event Log, you will need to take care of them first.

Comment: i can't do a full crawl... usually the crawl elaborate 1500-2000 pdfs in 15 minutes, but we have 720k pdfs stored, it will take 5 days more or less

Comment: ok thank you for your advice, i'll ask if it's possible to schedule it